# Styled-Components: Can't change parent component on Focus action

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have this HTML structure:

```
<SearchBarContainer>
   <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" style={{ marginRight: "5px" }} />
   <SearchBarText>What</SearchBarText>
   <SearchBar type="text" name="" />
   <SearchBarRightIcon>
      <FaCity />
   </SearchBarRightIcon>
</SearchBarContainer>
```

And this is my `styled-components`:

```
export const SearchBarContainer = styled.div`
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: .75rem 1rem;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #949494 !important;
`;

export const SearchBarRightIcon = styled.div`
    display:block;
    color: red;
    padding-left: 10px;
`;

export const SearchBar = styled.input`
    flex: 1;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 21px;

    &:focus{
        background: pink;
        // Let's remove the icon which is in the righ
        ${SearchBarContainer} {
            background: blue !important;
            box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(0,0,0,.175)!important;
        }
    
        ${SearchBarRightIcon} {
            display: none;
        }
    }
`;
```

And as you can see I have `&:focus` attribute, which only changes the background of itself element, but it doesn't work for `SearchBarRightIcon`, neither for `SearchBarContainer`. What's wrong? I have made a lot of active and hover attributes, which changes the parent elements, but it's my first time dealing with focus, what's wrong? How can I change the `SearchBarContainer` and `SearchBarRightIcon` when `focus` action is triggered?